# Create PreferenceFragmentCompat from activity_main.xml?

Tags: android

I have an app which it only has one layout, and that layout has some EditText fields that are used for settings. I want the data inside those EditText fields be used through out different classes in the app. Would I use PreferenceFragmentCompat for doing that?

I found out about SharedPreferences, but I'm having problems accessing the set string.

My MainActivity

```
private void initViews() {
    setDefaultAppButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_as_default);
    selectApns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apns);
    fromField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
    toField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
    messageField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    imageToSend = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    log = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.log);


    Pref.setDevicePhoneNumber(fromField.getText().toString());

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putString("devicePhoneNumber", fromField.getText().toString());
    prefs.edit().commit();

}
```

The code above works fine, but in the class below the keyword "this" is underlined red with the message "getDefaultSharedPreferences
(android.content.Context)
in PreferenceManager cannot be applied
to
(com.klinker.android.messaging_sample.SmsReceiver)
"

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
        String body = "";
        String originatingAddress = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i) {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
            body += sms.getMessageBody();
            originatingAddress = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
        }

        String from = (originatingAddress!=null && originatingAddress.length()>3)?(originatingAddress.replace("+", "")):("") ;


    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Log.d("Device Number","Device number: " + prefs.getString("devicePhoneNumber", "DEFAULT"));

    }

}
```

Comment: you can create a class with static fields where those data will be saved. then you can just use those fields across different classes in the app.

Comment: I created this class https://pastebin.com/MP9SWMnN I do set the values but it's blank when I read it in another class. Do you see anything I did wrong?

Comment: Static variables get lost when process goes away. It might be the case here. Have you tried saving in `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: can you see the edit please?

Comment: in the `BroadcastReceiver` `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`  try changing `this` to `context` ?

Comment: I made the change and context no longer give compile error. But instead of the phone number "DEFAULT" gets printed

Comment: it's all about getting the `context` right. what about putting `MainActivity.this` in both cases.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work also, since that method is overridden from a library. I get "com.klinker.android.messaging_sample.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167526/discussion-between-ruben-and-david).